# Secure sockets implementation

Tags: security, networking, winsock, packet

I am very new to networking, I am working on an old codebase from 2003 with a friend and we are having problems where we had some issues with packet spoofing and packet replay attacks. We have a client and server infrastructure using winsock 2 and overlapped I/O from what I can understand, what would be a relatively quick and easy way to add security without completly rewriting that part of the codebase?

Comment: Tunnel your application through ssh or stunnel.

Comment: Any links to example of that? or some books?

Comment: I hear [this site](http://google.com) is good.